Retrieve query parameters in Loading UI server side - NextJS v14
I'm trying to retrieve query parameters from the URL in the loading UI so the user knows the server is processing the correct data.
Normally, in page.tsx I would retrieve the query parameters like so:
export default async function page({
  searchParams
}: {
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) {
    return <></>;
}

When I do the same for loading.tsx though, searchParams just comes out as null.

I am aware that this could be solved by making it a client component, however I am displaying user sessions and whatnot so I cannot render it client side.
How should I solve this?

Here are some options:

Pass the search params as prop from the page to the component where you need it. This is good if you don't have many nested components to avoid prop drilling

or

Make the part of your component that need the search params a client component and then use it in your server component. Also in most cases, most loading ui or loaders are client components, so this should work pretty well.


I ended up doing the latter.
